# Updating Xcode looping the download process

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, software-update

In my trial to update my Xcode 7 to Xcode 8 on macOS Sierra:

1. I have opened Appstore and searched for Xcode.
   Beside the Xcode app I found the *Install* button and clicked it.
2. The 4.4GB Xcode finished download as per the gauge stuck to the bottom of the launchpad icon after waiting for 30min.
3. I didn't find the Xcode icon inside launchpad.
4. I tried to search Xcode but search didn't return any Xcode app.
5. I opened Appstore again to open the Xcode from inside Appstore.
6. I spotted the Xcode app in purchases of Appstore and found *Install* button instead of *Open* button beside it to my dismal.
7. I've gone ahead and clicked *Install* button and downloaded(4.4GB) again.
8. Now at 99.9% download failed. Appstore said
   [image]
9. Now in the launchpad I am happy to see a Xcode icon but I also found a broken icon downloading something which is 4.4GB; Obviously its Xcode.
   [image]
10. I am able to get rid of the broken icon by long clicking the icon and clicking the popped up 'X' on the jiggling icon.
11. I have encountered same issue a year ago when I updated Xcode6 to 7. This is definitely a serious bug; I have to download Xcode twice each time i try to update it.
12. I have filed a bug in bug reporter to which no one responds.
13. So I think its I'm the only one who is having the issue as I might have tampered something in the macOS. The App store still shows *Install* button besides the Xcode instead of *Open* button though its already got installed and I am using it. How to let know the Appstore that latest Xcode is already installed?

Comment: You don't need to let the App store "know" anything.  Just kill the download from the App store, then go into the `/Applications/ directory and remove the `XCode.app` that you don't want.

Comment: @Allan then why couldn't Appstore identify that the Xcode is already downloaded and wasted my limited bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

I had issues to download Xcode 8 from App Store too. Just when is going to finish installation process, something happened and Xcode started downloading again.

I just needed Xcode 8 installed as fast possible. So I just passed to another step.

Thank you Apple, for dev apps there is a alternative to download them. Any version of Xcode and its tools, you can download through [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com), to check all tools that you can download come to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). If you just need Xcode 8 this [link](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8/Xcode_8.xip) is your friend.

Now I have Xcode 7 and 8 in my system. You can delete your old Xcode 7 if you want.

Sure, you need at least a free apple dev account to download them. Just enter your appleID and agree to Apple terms.

**Note:** App Store shows me to update Xcode, maybe because I still have Xcode 7 installed.